# How to match pattern with Id on them react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-router-dom

I am new to react. I have a route with react router that takes `:id` as parameter, how do I match this using react-router-dom useLocation.

basically path can be `posts` or `post/21`
how do I match post/21 to render a component, I want to render a seperate component if I
am on the detail page

```
{path === 'post/:id' ? <PostDetail /> : <Posts /> }
```

but use location returns `posts/1` which I can't use to match the post detail

**summary**
`Any path that matches: post/:id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you will use a `Switch` component with a set of `Route` components. Each `Route` takes a path prop that is used for matching.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/post/:id">
          <PostDetail />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/post">
          <Posts />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Components that are children of a `Route` can use the `useRouteMatch` hook to access path params.

```js
const PostDetail = (props) => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  return <h1>{match.params.id}</h1>;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I just didn't very well in the documentation `useRouteMatch()` was what I was indeed looking for.